# Inductive proof of an infinite sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-writing, induction

Consider a sequence b<sub>n</sub> (containing infinite amount of values) with values in ℝ, indexed by ℕ. Suppose the range of  b<sub>n</sub> is contained in the finite interval [a, b].

Use the Principle of Mathematical Induction to prove that for any *n* ∈ ℕ, there is an interval of length <sup>(b-a)</sup>⁄<sub>2<sup>n</sup></sub>,  *k* ≥ 1, which contains infinitely many terms of the sequence

I can understand it intuitively, b<sub>n</sub> has infinite terms, so there exists a subset of b<sub>n</sub> that also has infinite terms. However, I am not sure how I would go about predicting this inductively.

Comment: Hint: if $[x, y]$ contains infinitely many $b_n$, what can you say about (at least one of) $[x, z]$ and $[z, y]$ where $z = (x+y)/2$ is the midpoint of $[x, y]$?

Comment: It would be infinite, correct? but I am not sure how to prove that either

Comment: Well what can you say if both $[x, z]$ and $z, y]$ contained only finitely many $b_n$? Could there be infinitely many distinct $b_n$ in that case?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that. Are you saying if b<sub>n</sub>  had a finite number of elements? In that scenario wouldn't both intervals also have a finite number of elements?

Comment: I am asking you to think about what will be the induction step in your proof. You'll have an inductive hypothesis that an interval $[x, y]$ contains infinitely many of the $b_n$ and you'll need to come up with an interval with length $(x-y)/2$ which also contains infinitely many of the $b_n$. Over to you ....

Answer (score 1):

Base case $n = 0$

The interval $(a,b)$ has infinitely many members of $\{b_n\}$.

Inductive hypothesis:

Suppose there is an interval of lenght $\frac {(b-a)}{2^n}$ that contains infinitely many points.  Lets call this interval $(c,d)$

We must show that if when the hypothesis is true it implies that there is an interval of length $\frac {(b-a)}{2^{n+1}}$ that contains infinitely many points.

$(c, \frac {c+d}{2})$ and $(\frac {c+d}{2}, d)$ are sub-intervals of (c,d) each or length $\frac {(b-a)}{2^{n+1}}$

At least one of $(c, \frac {c+d}{2})$ and $(\frac {c+d}{2}, d)$ has infinitely many points.  i.e. if neither do, then $(c,d)$ does not have infinitely many points, and that would contradict our assumption.

QED